# XML to CSV using XSLT: how to exclude the XML version?

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt

**XML example:**

```
<message>
  <string>anyvalue</string>
</message>
```

**XSL example:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
            extension-element-prefixes="exsl" 
            version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="message">
  <xsl:value-of select="string"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm converting this XML into a CSV-File. The CSV is supposed to just include the "anyvalue" but my actual output is

**CSV:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>anyvalue
```

(The XML version is in the same column as "anyvalue")
Excluding the XML version is very important in my case.
I wrote my converter with Java, if you have got something like a method to delete the version for example. I would prefer changes in the XSL but any solution is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xsl:output method="text"/>` in your XSLT as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`. If you want help with Java then show your current Java code.

Comment: I suppose my question was a little stupid. Thanks for the quick answer! (I'd love to accept it but it takes 10 minutes until one may accept an answer.)